# Arduino Micro Cannot get Interrupt 6 work on PIN 7

Tags: arduino-micro

After finding out about the situation with pin7 from this tutorial:

https://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=35847

```
    void setup(){

    EICRB |= (1<<ISC60)|(0<<ISC61); // sets the interrupt type for EICRB (INT6).
                                  // EICRA sets interrupt type for INT0...3

    /*
    ISCn0  ISCn1   Where n is the interrupt. 0 for 0, etc
      0      0   Triggers on low level
      1      0   Triggers on edge
      0      1   Triggers on falling edge
      1      1   Triggers on rising edge
    */
EIMSK |= (1<<INT6); // activates the interrupt. 6 for 6, etc

void loop(){
//do other things here
}

ISR(INT6_vect) {
  // interrupt code goes here
  }
```

I have set:

```
EICRB |= (0<<ISC60)|(0<<ISC61);
```

Because I need it to be triggered on LOW.

I could still not get it work on the micro. IF I use the pin as regular input pin I can clearly see LOW/HIGHs on pin 7 with digitalread.

I have a sensor attached there which goes LOW in case it is triggered.

I wonder if anybody knows what else can I try to get it work. I already hardwired everything in my circuit board, there are no more free interrupts and no way to change them.

Comment: ORing with 0 does nothing.

Comment: And did you define an ISR?

Answer (score 1):

I've used following code and loopback from pin 8 to pin 7:

```
// loopback:  pin 8 -> pin 7

void setup() {
  pinMode(7, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN_TX, OUTPUT); // to see pin 8 logic level on TX led
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT); // toggled by ISR

  EICRB |= _BV(ISC60);  // Triggers on edge
  EIMSK |= _BV(INT6);   // activates the interrupt
}

ISR(INT6_vect) {
  PINC = _BV(PC7);  // toggle led 13 (@ PC7)
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN_TX, HIGH);

  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN_TX, LOW);
  delay(500);

}
```

And it works perfectly. Only problem I can imagine is to figure out correctly which pin is really 7 as label is on the right side of pin (not under nor left).